# How does accuracy increase in ensemble learning?

Tags: probability, ensemble-learning

I have a doubt from a passage in the ensemble learning chapter of Aurelien Geron's book "hands on machine learning... ".

[image]

I do not understand

> If you do the math, you will find that the probability of obtaining a
> majority of heads after 1,000 tosses is close to 75%. The more you
> toss the coin, the higher the probability (e.g., with 10,000 tosses,
> the probability climbs over 97%).

Is it not still 51%? How does it increase to 75%?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused over two completely different things here: the share of *head* for a this slightly biased coin will tend towards 51% (see **Law of Large Numbers**). With that, however, the probability of getting a **majority outcome** *head* will increase as well. Apparently, for 1.000 flips it will be 75% but it will tend towards 100% since the more the share of *head* will tend towards 51%, the more likely a majority of *head* outcomes will get.

Comment: Can I think of this as the probability of majority outcome increasing with the more tosses made because e.g. for 100 tosses, 51 heads 49 tails. 51-49 = 2, for 1000 tosses 510 heads 490 tails. 510-490 = 20, for 10000 tosses 5100 heads 4900 tails. 5100-4900 = 200. As this difference is larger for larger number of tosses we can say that the probability of majority outcome increases with larger number of tosses?

Comment: I would say this touches the truth but it's rather unintuitive regarding the actual explanation - but yes it's about the number of rows/flips. Imagine starting to row an ordinary dice. You wouldn't be super surprised to row 3x a 'one'  at the beginning (although unlikely). However, when the dice is unbiased, this should level out over time to the 'ones' having a share of 1/6 across all rowed sites/eyes. So when the coin tends towards it's actual 49/51 probability, then automatically the majority of head (51%) will get more likely. **So it really comes down to the Law of Large Numbers**

Comment: The probability of obtaining a majority of heads in a given number of coin tosses can be calculated using the binomial probability formula. P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1 - p)^{n - k}
  For the majority of heads, you would want k to be greater than half of n (e.g., if n=1,000, then k>500 for a majority). This probability increases as n becomes bigger.

https://shiny.rit.albany.edu/stat/binomial/